# Make a div element "think" that the screen with is a certain width?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, media-queries

Curious whether there is a way to make an element think that the viewport is a certain width?

This would be used to test responsive CSS utilities.  For example this [CSS component is responsive](https://superflycss.github.io/component-navbox/target/test/html/), but to see the behavior users have to make the browser window smaller.

If there was a way to "Trick" the markup test elements into thinking that the viewport was a certain width the manual dragging of the browser window would not be necessary.

One possibility, although I doubt it's implemented, is for the browser developer tooling to expose an API that allowed us to select and inform the browser that certain elements should consider the browser to be rendered at a certain viewport size ...

## A Way

While fiddling around with [this test](https://superflycss.github.io/component-navbox/target/test/html/) I accidentally discovered that there is a way to trigger the media queries without developer tooling and that is to zoom the viewport with ctrl +.  That will trigger the media queries, although not with declarative precision that I'm looking for obviously.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve... media queries are **designed** to trigger at certain viewport widths. Typically you'd just resize your browser (or alternatively, use the F12 Tools) to test how the website looks at a certain width. Are you trying to have one element not 'obey' your media queries? If that's the case... why not simply write the queries in such a way that the target element is excluded from them? Or create a rule such that it has the same properties when the window is shrunk?

Comment: I'm trying to side step having to manipulate the view size in the developer tools.  For example there is a responsive utility like `u-sm-padding-2rem` that sets padding, but only if the viewport is small, then the test would show this without the developer having to simulate a small viewport inside the developer tooling.

Comment: Here's an example of some layout tests.  I have not built responsive ones yet, because of the "Having to size the viewport requirement", and if I included them now and the viewer would have to manually set the viewport size (Via dev tools) to see that the tests are executing the right way:https://superflycss.github.io/utilities-layout/target/test/html/

Comment: So the question asks for the inverse of a media query.  Instead of triggering CSS given a viewport size, make the browser believe that the viewport is a certain size for a certain element, such that the media query triggers.

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean now. But no, I don't think such a mechanism exists. And wouldn't that defeat the purpose in the first please? Because surely you'd want a different display for your end users at a desktop width... and the developer would need to be able to simulate *that* as well. There would be no way to know which one of the two views you were requesting. I suppose you could build that 'switch' functionality into a browser extension or something, but it would still require a click, and for the amount of effort, `F12` then `CTRL + SHIFT + M` is probably just as quick as a click...

Comment: @Ole, yes, it's possible and it's quite simple to achieve. The more complex part is explaining how CSS actually works, as your understanding of it is currently skewed. I'm not criticizing, none of us knew CSS before we learned it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge if you for example look at the test https://superflycss.github.io/component-navbox/target/test/html/ you'll notice that at differerent viewport sizes the rendering of the component changes, depending on what type of modifier is attached to the component `--sm, --md, --large`.  But the trigger the media query that viewport size has to change.  Ideally we could put the component inside an element that "Thinks" that the viewport is at a certain size, such that it renders the component the way it would render when the viewport actually has that size.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu if you look at any of the SuperflyCSS repositories https://github.com/superflycss you'll see that almost all of them have associated visual tests that progressively explain the component or utility.  I built all of these and the purpose is to test and explain how the CSS works.  Both responsive and normal css components and utilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in an `<iframe>`. This tag creates a new window context, the width of which media queries are compared against. The iframe width can be manipulated to emulate different device widths, per this example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJNyJd

An `<iframe>` is used by the Material Design resizer tester to emulate different screens sizes in-browser:

https://material.io/tools/resizer/

As far as I know this is the only way to accomplish this.